# reCaptcha v3. Captcha always fail if form submitted twice

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to use the new captcha but as the title says, it fails if I submit a form twice.

I read that I should reset my token after submitting which I tried doing

```
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            // do request for recaptcha token
            // response is promise with passed token
            grecaptcha.execute('6LeH6Y4UAAAAABwpPXv0NjMAQp56WypP5hFz45ZM', {
                    action: 'contactus'
                })
                .then(function(token) {
                    // add token value to form
                    document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = token;
                });
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to verify the recaptcha again for 2nd form submission.
why do you need to submit the same form twice anyway?

Comment: Not necessarily the same content in the form. I am verifying it on every submit.

Comment: You need to reset recaptcha (`grecaptcha.reset()`) before submitting the form again.